# DataTables: how to reorder a column in datatables using Javascript or any function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using **ColReorder** extension of **datatables**. And I want to rearrange a column in a table using some function and not manually dragging the column. I know there is a function `order()` which takes an array as parameter.

But this method is not good to move a single column at a time as it has performance constraints when number of columns are large

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass array with new `order`:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({ colReorder: true });

$('button#newOrder').click(function() {
    table.colReorder.order([3,4,2,0,1], true);
});
```

See more details here https://datatables.net/reference/api/colReorder.order()